# SublimeLinter-pep8 only uses the first ignore parameter in my config file

Tags: python

I'm using SublimeLinter to lint Python, and I configured SublimeLinter.sublime-settings following the instructions at this RealPython post on [Setting Up Sublime Text 3 for Full Stack Python Development](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/). This seems to be a very popular setup, given how high it comes up on the Google SERP for various searches related to Python and Sublime Text 3. Also, the comments are very positive, and the author is quite responsive.

The problem I'm having is that I used the suggested configuration for the SublimeLinter.sublime-settings file:

```
"pep8": {
    "@disable": false,
    "args": [],
    "excludes": [],
    "ignore": "E501,C0301,W0142,W0402,R0201,E1101,E1102,C0103,R0901,R0903,R0904,C1001,W0223,W0232,W0201,E1103,R0801,C0111",
    "max-line-length": 100,
    "select": ""
},
```

However the linter is only ignoring the first error code in the "ignore" parameter. As I Python beginner, I decided to be slightly less aggressive with the codes to ignore, and set my config file as follows:

```
"pep8": {
    "@disable": false,
    "args": [],
    "excludes": [],
    "ignore": "E251, W291, E501",
    "max-line-length": null,
    "select": ""
},
```

However only the first error code is being ignored. This happens regardless of what order I put the codes in. The author of the article responded to my question, but couldn't answer it. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the spaces between the error codes solved the problem.

I.e.

```
"ignore": "E251, W291, E501",
```

changed to

```
"ignore": "E251,W291,E501",
```

Answer (score 1):

Need quotes around each code you want to ignore:

```
"pep8": {
    "@disable": false,
    "args": [],
    "excludes": [],
    "ignore": [ "E251", "W291", "E501" ],
    "max-line-length": null,
    "select": ""
},
```

Comment: This works, but there is another step you added that needs to be documented: in addition to adding quotes around each quotes, you have to put the entire list of quotes in brackets.